# How to adjust a data for MLP to LSTM (expected ndim=3, found ndim=2 Error)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, data-processing

I have the data that working on Multi-Layer Perceptron architecture looks like this

```
X_train_feature.shape
(52594, 16)

X_train_feature[0]
array([1.18867208e-03, 1.00000000e+00, 8.90000000e+01, 8.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00])

y_train
(52594, 2)

y_train[0].toarray()
array([[0., 1.]])
```

By the first dimension: number samples
and the second: for the X_train is the number of features and in the y_train is one-hot encoder.

And I want to use the same data on LSTM/Bi-LSTM, so I copy the code from the internet and change a input value to same as MLP

```
def define_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(20, input_shape=X_train_feature[0].shape, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])  # compile
    print('Total params: ', model.count_params())
    return model
```

But When I try to create a model the error about input shape will be append

```
model = define_model()
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_30: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

What should I need to adjust my data to apply on LSTM or I need to change an architecture config? Thank you so much.

Comment: your input shape is wrong , try `input_shape = X_train.shape`,it should be of 3 dimension

Comment: I edited in a section of input_shape for ```X_train_feature.shape``` it returns 2 dim ```(52594, 16)``` because this data is for MLP, the dimension is 2 and I find the way to change to 3 dim.

Comment: it will not work untill input is in shape `(batch_size,seq_len,features_dim)`,what is your input anyway

Comment: ```(Number of samples, Number of features)``` I need to find the way to change it to 3D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LSTM (unlike a perceptron) is not a feed-forwarding network. It needs a history to predict the next point. So, a proper input tensor to a LSTM should be of shape `(timesteps, num_features)` meaning that each sample is a sequence of `timesteps` observations such that the cell state is initiated in the first observation of the sequence and goes through the entire sequence.

Therefore, the input tensor should have the shape `(num_sequences, seq_length, num_features)` where:

- `num_sequences`: number of samples, i.e. how many sequences do you have to train the model?
- `seq_length`: How long these sequences are. for variable-length sequences, you can supply `None`.
- `num_features`: How many features does have a single observation in a given sequence?

Comment: So, I just need to reshape my data to ```(52594,None, 16)``` Right?

Comment: @Peerat No. Before start rewriting your code, you'd need to understand what's going to be fed into the LSTM. You should consider a rolling window over your data. This window specifies the timesteps i.e. sequences. Please search google for "keras lstm timesteps", there's lots of useful write-ups that get you started.

Answer (score 0):

The input to a LSTM layer is a 3d tensor, with shape (data_length, timesteps, n_features)

To have that, you first have to transform your data using something like:

```py
   def slice_data(self, data, n_steps, n_ahead=1):
        X_data = data.drop(['y'], axis=1)
        y_data = data['y']
        X = []
        y = []
        for i in range(len(X_data)):
            end_point = i + n_steps
            if end_point + n_ahead > len(X_data)-1:
                break
            slice_x, slice_y = X_data[i:end_point], y_data.loc[end_point]
            X.append(slice_x)
            y.append(slice_y)
        X, y = np.array(X), np.array(y)
        self.n_features = X.shape[2]
        X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], X.shape[1], X.shape[2]))
        return X, y
```

Or you can use a tool like the one I made myself: [EasyLSTM](https://github.com/luizmlo/EasyLSTM)
EasyLSTM can shape your input array into a LSTM-friendly one in just a single line of code